# Mismatch between Chrome Task Manager CPU usage (100%) and Performance Profile (idle)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, cpu-usage

I have a webpage I'm trying to debug in Chrome v67.0.3396.62. Intermittently the page becomes unresponsive, and both Windows Task Manager and Chrome's built in Task Manager show 100% CPU usage [on a single core].

This problem does not happen in any reliable or reproducible way - I can go days without a problem, then have issues for hours and have to end the tab process in order to regain use of it every time the page loads.

I have somehow managed to capture a performance profile using Chrome's Dev tools performance tab during a time that this problem was occurring.  However, the profile shows the process to be mostly idle.

**What could cause 100% cpu usage that is not captured by the dev tools performance profiling?**

(I have already poured over my own code for infinite loops/recursion, but haven't found anything suspect.  I am using jquery, bootstrap and popper, but they're all being served from reputable CDNs and match their integrity hashes, so I'm at a loss how to debug any further. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.)

Comment: You should provide the code.